# Voltage output of AC current clamp

Tags: current, ac, current-measurement, oscilloscope

So I'm using a Fluke i200s current clamp in combination with an  oscilloscope to measure the AC current. Normal current clamps have a current output, but this one has a voltage as output. Now my question is does this clamp has the same working principle as the others(like a transformer with one primary winding), and just measures the voltage instead of the current. Or does this clamp works differently, and how?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: It probably just has a precision shunt built in.

Comment: Yes I did @PlasmaHH  this is from the instruction sheet: Output level(s) 100 mV/A
10mV/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The Fluke I200S current clamp.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Dnly.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. The internal wiring.*

> Now my question is does this clamp has the same working principle as the others(like a transformer with one primary winding), and just measures the voltage instead of the current.

It is a true current transformer but with a shunt resistor built in. The current will create a voltage drop across the resistor and this voltage is monitored by the oscilloscope.

Comment: Is there a reason that they use the shunt resistor?

Comment: Yes. Your oscilloscope has a 1M input impedance. If the current transformer tried to push 10 mA through that, for example, the voltage would have to rise to \$ IR = 1M \cdot 10m = 10 \ \mathrm kV \$. You don't want that. The 'scope inputs are *voltage* inputs, not current. A resistor is a perfect current to voltage converter!